# How does ActiveMQ ProducerFlowControl work for Async Topics?

Tags: java, performance, activemq-classic

We are using ActiveMQ 5.3.1 as a standalone broker in our system, and every so often we get a big spike in messages (intentional, for example on failover, we re-subscribe). We currently have ProducerFlowControl turned on, as this seemed a sensible way to stop components from falling over during these spikes.

However, it seems we have an issue with the Flow Control - once it kicks in, the Producers seem to lock indefinitely, even once all inflight messages have been consumed. As soon as we see the message

```
Usage Manager memory limit (1048576) reached
```

Our producers can no longer send any messages to the topic. This seems odd - I thought it would be more of a "one-in-one-out" policy. I read somewhere that FlowControl does not work very well for Async Topic producers (which is exactly what we have) so I am wondering if there is a better way to configure this?

Also, how long does Flow Control last once it has kicked in? Will it throttle producers on that topic forever (until ActiveMQ is restarted? until producers are restarted?) or does it last a fixed or configurable amount of time (eg it waits for consumer to empty the topic, then waits 5 minutes)?

Any help would be appreciated. We are currently investigating turning Flow Control off and using File-based cursors instead. Any obvious downside with that approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Producer Flow Control occurs when you hit one of the size limits (memory, disk, etc.) for either the entire broker or a single destination.  Once you hit it, producers on that destination (or the whole broker, depending on which limit you hit) are unable to send more messages until enough space frees up to hold the next one.  So your one-out-one-in mental model is the right one (though if the messages are of different sizes, then it might not be truly one-for-one).  This will continue for as long as the limit continues to be hit because producers are faster than consumers; it's not time-based, and it's not forever, just until consumers start catching up and you're not running into any limits.

If you're hitting PFC, it could mean that you haven't properly sized some limit in your broker to handle bursts of data or periods where consumers are offline (so you should stop and do that, not turn off PFC), or that you have a systemic problem where your producers are always going to outrun your consumers (so you need to either speed up your consumers, slow down your producers, find a way to allow multiple consumers to consume messages in parallel, or configure the broker to drop some of your messages for you).

Or it could mean that your topics have some leftover durable subscriptions for consumers that are currently (permanently?) offline, and the broker has to keep those messages so it can deliver them when the consumer comes back online (which it might never do).  Because the broker's got to hold onto those messages, it can't allow any new ones to be sent, even though the currently online consumers have processed their copies of all of the messages.  This one's my best guess based on what you've written, though it could certainly be other things instead.

In any case, PFC kicking in is almost certainly just a secondary symptom of something else wrong with how you've designed your system, and you should figure that out and fix it rather than just turning off PFC.  (After all, if you're perpetually producing faster than you can consume, writing messages to disk is just going to run you out of disk space if you turn out of PFC.)

Most importantly, 5.3.1 is **VERY, VERY** old, and there have been a **TON** of improvements between then and 5.10.0 (the current released version).  I wouldn't even consider running a broker on anything before 5.5.1 because of all of the bugs that were found in the versions before it, but really I wouldn't recommend running on anything before 5.8.0 and there'd have to be a good reason not to just go all the way to 5.10.0.  And you're certainly not going to get any support for 5.3.1 from the community if you hit something that you think might be a bug, so do yourself a favor and upgrade to a version that was released more recently than 2010.  (And hopefully just upgrading will fix the bad behavior you're seeing, but if not, you'll be in a better position to ask for someone to troubleshoot the problem.)

Comment: Thanks Tim - I know it makes sense to upgrade, and we have a plan to do that. The problem is we have a load of client applications that were distributed with the activemq client jar for 5.3.1, and I'm worried that there might be compatibility issues between client 5.3.1 and server 5.10.0. I know I can probably google this, but off the top of your head, do you know if there would be any issues? Are server/client versions backwards/forwards compatible, or do we have to upgrade clients and server at the same time?

Comment: In fact, I just remembered this question that I had a few months ago, when I first suggested to the powers that be that we upgrade our infrastructure (got no answers on the question though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696125/activemq-client-5-3-connecting-to-server-5-9-with-failover

Comment: Different versions of ActiveMQ are theoretically supposed to be backwards-compatible, but there's no formal testing done and empirical evidence (including [this recent email to the mailing list](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Can-a-produce-and-consumer-running-on-different-activemq-versions-exchange-messages-td4680200.html#a4687320) suggests that some versions aren't compatible in practice.  I'd recommend you email the ActiveMQ users list to see if anyone's tried 5.3.1 with any of the more recent versions, but you may not find anyone who has, so testing yourself may be your only option.